# How to return a Json object from a C# method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to fix an ASP.NET WebAPI method where a Json response is required. However it's returning a string instead.

Initially it was returing XML format, but I've added this line to the mvc code in App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs in order to return Json by default.

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

We've updated the c# method as follows to use NewtonSoft:

```
public string Get()
{
    string userid = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "userid", "");
    string pwd = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "pwd", "");
    string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.openSession(userid, pwd);

    JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
    string jsonresp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp);

    return resp;
}
```

The resp var is coming back as a string type:

```
"{status:\"SUCCESS\",data:[\"4eb97d2c6729df98206cf214874ac1757649839fe4e24c51d21d\"]}"
```

and jsonresp var looks like this :

```
"\"{status:\\\"SUCCESS\\\",data:[\\\"4eb97d2c6729df98206cf214874ac1757649839fe4e24c51d21d\\\"]}\""
```

and in Chrome's F12 dev tools, the data object is :

```
""{status:\"SUCCESS\",data:[\"4eb97d2c6729df98206cf214874ac1757649839fe4e24c51d21d\"]}""
```

and in Console tools, the result of angular.fromJson(data) :

```
"{status:"SUCCESS",data:["4eb97d2c6729df98206cf214874ac1757649839fe4e24c51d21d"]}"
```

I would appreciate some advice on how to properly return the Json object, and NOT in any string type.

---

#### UPDATE

By intercepting the `resp` var, and using Mr. Chu's suggestion below, I can successfully achieve a nice clean Json object on the client.
The key is that `resp` needs to contains double quotes around both key:value pairs:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    string userid = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "userid", "");
    string pwd = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "pwd", "");
    string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.openSession(userid, pwd);

    resp = "{\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"data\":[\"194f66366a6dee8738428bf1d730691a9babb77920ec9dfa06cf\"]}";  // TEST !!!!!           

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(resp, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

in Chrome console, the response is :

```
Object {status: "SUCCESS", data: Array[1]}
data: Array[1]
status: "SUCCESS"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is `resp`? Is it a JSON string?

Comment: WebApi will convert it to JSON for you automatically (assuming you have it set up properly). Don't convert it to JSON and try just returning the C# object.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`resp` is already a JSON string, but it is not valid JSON (the keys are not wrapped in quotes (`"`). If it is returned to angular, the JavaScript JSON.parse() method is unable to deserialize it. However, you can use JSON.NET in deserialize it to a JObject and serialize it again into valid JSON and create your own `HttpResponseMessage`...

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    string userid = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "userid", "");
    string pwd    = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "pwd", "" );

    string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.openSession(userid, pwd);
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(resp);

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(jObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

Or you can just return the `JObject` and have Web API serialize it for you...

```
public JObject Get()
{
    string userid = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "userid", "");
    string pwd    = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "pwd", "" );

    string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.openSession(userid, pwd);
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(resp);

    return jObject;
}
```

In either case, the Web API call should return this JSON, which is now valid...

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "data": [
    "4eb97d2c6729df98206cf214874ac1757649839fe4e24c51d21d"
  ]
}
```

In the angular code, you'd have to dig out the session id which is stored in an array called `data`...

```
userService.openUserSession(rzEnvJson).then(function (response) {
    var sessionResponse = response.data; // or simply response, depending if this is a promise returned from $http
    $rootScope.rgSessionVars.sessionID = sessionResponse.data[0];
});
```

Comment: I've updated my original post to show the change - now using NewtonSoft's JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

Comment: Have you tried this answer? Seems like it should do what you want.

Comment: I'm getting a front end error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token s at Object.parse (native)"

Comment: It looks like `resp` contains invalid JSON. `status` and `data` should be wrapped in `"`s. The `s` that the error is complaining about is the `s` in `status`.

Comment: @bob I've updated my answer to show how you can use JSON.NET to convert the invalid JSON from `DynAggrClientAPI.openSession` into valid JSON and return it to Angular.

Comment: I've updated my original post to reflect your new code, as well as manually intercepting the `resp` var which re-formats the string with double quotes. My c++ guy will fix that part.

Comment: anthony, I've also tried your JObject idea, and it also works like a charm against the invalid Json string.

Comment: public JObject Get() methods works for me, Thank you so much

Answer (score 8):

The key to what is going on here is in the comment made by [Mike Cheel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426422/mike-cheel); serialization is happening twice, once in the OP's code and once by `Asp.Net WebAPI`. That is why a string is returned instead of a `Json` object.

I was encountering the exact same thing. Here is a hello world example showing the problem. I first did something like this:

```
[Route("getall")]
public string GetAllItems()
{
    var result = new
    {
        x = "hello",
        y = "world"
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

I then tried to so something like this, thinking that I needed to return `IHttpActionResult` to resolve this:

```
[Route("getall")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllItems()
{
    var result = new
    {
        x = "hello",
        y = "world"
    };
    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
}
```

Both these controller actions gave me a string rather than the Json object that I was wanting; so I go this:

```
"{\"x\":\"hello\",\"y\":\"world\"}"
```

Finally I saw the comment by Mike and realized that I needed to return the .Net object *directly* and just let `WebAPI` handle the serialization. So instead of returning this:

```
return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

return this:

```
return Ok(result);
```

Then I got the result that I was expecting:

```
{"x":"hello","y":"world"}
```

Comment: I know you found that return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)); was causing an issue.  I'm just glad you posted that code because that code was what SOLVED the issue I was having.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what this has to do with AngularJS, but your problem is simple. Your data object is JSON encoded. So you could almost certainly access `data.JsonRequestBehavior` and it would be `1`. But your Data field inside it is AGAIN JSON-encoded. You need to decode it before trying to use it - it's just a string when you get to this callback:

```
var myData = angular.fromJson(data.Data);
console.log(myData.data);
```

Note that your data.Data object is itself another wrapper - an array. You almost certainly want `myData.data[0]` to go into that sessionID field...

Comment: PS, this is all probably happening because you're doing `string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.openSession( userid, pwd ); ` and taking the result as a string. You didn't include code for it, but if you have this return a real object, your JSON encoder can probably avoid the double-encoding and let you skip the step above.

Comment: the 'resp' var is indeed the source of contention here. It's a C++ program that return this. I will need that coder to return some kind of Json-formatted object, I assume.

Comment: we've updated the code to use JsonSerializer(). My data result is now coming back as ""{status:\"SUCCESS\",data:[\"9f9502cd3e0a81cab3b2c7b4fc65395b0b40741130c7aead498a\"]}""

Comment: in the meantime, I'm pulling out the data: field by first applying JSON.parse(data) then using the .split() function to access the data: field. It's not ideal, but works in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

These other solutions weren't working for me, but I was able to get something like this to work:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     string userid = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "userid", "");
     string pwd = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "pwd", "");    
     
     await using (Stream contentStream = await DynAggrClientAPI.openSessionStreamAsync(userid, pwd, cancellationToken))
     {
         Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
         Response.ContentType = "application/json";
         await contentStream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body, cancellationToken);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (raw json in string, like `resp`) and this worked fine for me in .Net 6.  I haven't checked previous versions.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    string userid = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "userid", "");
    string pwd    = UrlUtil.getParam(this, "pwd", "" );

    string resp = DynAggrClientAPI.openSession(userid, pwd);
    return Content(resp, "application/json"):
}
```