# Web API json responds faulty json

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to deserialize an json response using NewtonSoft JSON framework.
Now the serialization goes as planned, no errors there. Now if I try to deserialize my JSON response coming back from the server I'm getting an error.

`{"Error converting value 
    \"{\"DefaultLocation\":{\"LocationID\":\"0d052c27-1127-4da7-8434-e43dfcf8e58e\",\"ShortName\":\"Central Labo\"},
    \"OrderTypes\":[{\"OrderTypeID\":\"db5fcdf0-9a92-e011-a9de-00155d000505\",\"OrderShortName\":\"Order Type QM\"}]}\" 
    to type 'CSD.WebAPI.Classes.ExternalLotInfo'. Path '', line 1, position 225."}`

No ofcourse I consulted JSON lint and it gave me the same error.
[image: JSON Error]

Now when I do my call from my unit test with following code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void can_get_Information_For_ExternalLot()
    {
        ExternalLotInfo externalLotInfo;
        var client = new ApiClient<Dto>("linktoserver/CSD4API/api/quality");
        Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("site", "europe");

        var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        client.GetDtoAsync("GetInformationForExternalLot", parameters, (response) =>
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
            Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content);

            externalLotInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExternalLotInfo>(response.Content.ToString());

            resetEvent.Set();
        });
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

gave me the following response

```
"\"{\\\"DefaultLocation\\\":{\\\"LocationID\\\":\\\"0d052c27-1127-4da7-8434-e43dfcf8e58e\\\",\\\"ShortName\\\":\\\"Central Labo\\\"},\\\"OrderTypes\\\":[{\\\"OrderTypeID\\\":\\\"db5fcdf0-9a92-e011-a9de-00155d000505\\\",\\\"OrderShortName\\\":\\\"Order Type QM\\\"}]}\""
```

So ofcourse again to JSONLint
[image]

Pretty clear right. The JSON that is responded trough my API & test is faulty. I get that but I can't seem to figure out why if I surf to the location of my API my JSON is responded correctly.
[image]
[image]

Can someone see the difference between my 3 different calls why there is a difference in JSON responses ?

Serialize Function

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetInformationForExternalLot")]
    public string GetInformationForExternalLot(string site)
    {
        _qualityRepository = new QualityRepository(site);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_qualityRepository.GetInformationForExternalLot());
    }
```

In this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5UDWwuXn) I attached my additional code

Comment: That's because you're serializing your JSON yourself. Don't do that, WebAPI does that for you. Change the return type to the type of your model (`QualityRepository` instead of `string`) and skip the serialization, or return an HttpResponseMessage. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145609/how-to-return-a-json-object-from-a-c-sharp-method). The browser screenshot also does not show "valid JSON", it shows your JSON string wrapped in an XML document.

Comment: Isn't that a bit harsh to like close my question in an instance ?

Comment: Okay now i can see you updated your comment. Why in heavens name would I respond my enitre repository ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the type that `QualityRepository.GetInformationForExternalLot()` returns, `ExternalLotInfo`. The point is, if you return something from a WebAPI method, WebAPI will serialize that for you. If you return a JSON string, WebAPI will _wrap that in a JSON string_, causing the escaping you see. This is (partially) explained in the duplicate.